# Detected problems with app native libraries

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android

When I upgrade the target sdk version to 25 the following popup shows while working with the app

[image]

I couldn't find any proper solution on this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when this accurs (popup)

Comment: can u update ur gradle here

Comment: the popup occurs on the start of the application

Comment: thats y can u send ur gradle here..?

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to [Xamarin Android 7.0](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/), you can find the following statements:

> Note: Due to a change by Google, [Android N will now only permit linking to NDK-provided native libraries](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk). libsqlite.so is not an NDK-provided native library. Consequently, existing apps using e.g. Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll will crash when running on Android N. This may include other SQLite-using assemblies, not distributed with Xamarin.Android.

But the latest [sqlite-net-pcl 1.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.3.3) have already fixed the Android N native library problem. So to fix the issue, you need to update your Sqlite-net-pcl of your project to the latest version.

Comment: I've update mine to the latest 1.4.118 and still get the issue.  My case might be a bit different because I'm getting this message only once after I resume my app from putting it in the background (ex. I press the key to show all running apps and select my app)